# Pass custom page_title to user_engagement event in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

is there a way to pass a custom page title to user engagement event in google analytics?

We are using a function to pass a custom pageTitle to page_view and using GTM to pass paage_title using the pageTitle variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJz3w.png)

Can we do the same for user_engagement event as well? I was not able to find anything related to this.

We haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `datalayer variable` in GTM.

[image]

2. Modify the GTM's GA configuration. Add `page_title` in fields to set

[image]

3. Then you should see the `page_title` change in ga4 debug view

[image]

Comment: Thank you appreciate it. I'll try this also, do I have to send a page view event when this configuration loads?